# Angular DI circular reference when subscribing

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, rxjs, circular-reference

I have two questions.

There is a full code example provided here: [STACKBLITZ EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviorsubject-example-ndcfzq?file=src/app/services/user.service.ts)

I need some explanation whether I understand it the right way or not. There is a short code snippet from the example:

```
 this.userService.castUser.subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user
      console.log(this); // <this> keyword here
    });
```

1. Does passing a callback function working on `this` in the subscribe method create a circular reference between the component and the service? Something like the registered callback function in the service subscribers array points to the component instance which has the service instance injected, and this service has the subscribers array where there is the callback function pointing to the component instance, and so on and so on.
2. What is the actual benefit of subscribing to observable rather than the subject itself? Can't we make `user` public and subscribe to it rather than to `castUser`?

   ```
   private user = new BehaviorSubject<string>('john');
   castUser = this.user.asObservable();
   ```

Comment: 1) No, this is component scope and so is the callback 2) you can public the subject and use it directly, however, it depends if you also want to allow consumers to next() the subject. If not, asObservable fixes that.

Comment: 1) but reference to `this` from callback (which is actually the component object) must be stored somewhere in the service to do some operations on it when a new value is emitted, isn't it this way? In my example, I print the component object in the console, with every new user.

Answer (score 0):

1. using `this` in an arrow function does reflect the actual `this` element during instantiation of this function. In your case `this` does reflect the component the subscription function was defined in.
2. The actual benefit is managing complexity. Defining user as public would result in potentially multiple places in your application, where this variable can be changed. If you are the only one working on a codebase, this is rather fine. If you have multiple developers it is harder to prevent.
   To ensure that variables cannot be changed from another place as intended, I would actually encourage you to use the following approach

```
private readonly user = new BehaviorSubject<string>('john');
get castUser() {
  return this.user.asObservable();
}
```

**Update after feedback from comment**
If you want to also perform some operations in the service, you should use rxjs operators in order to do this. I assume you want to perform some "sideeffect" like accessing properties from your service. In order to do this, you should use `tap` operator:

```
private readonly user = new BehaviorSubject<string>('john');
get castUser() {
  return this.user.asObservable().pipe(tap(user => {this.variableFromMyService = user}));
}
```

**Another update after comment**
you can achieve binding the service as `this` to the function by removing the arrow declaration and binding the service to this function. Nevertheless I can't think of a reasonable scenario for this. The code below should work nevertheless:

```
this.injectedService.subscribe(
(function() {
    console.log(this); //this will be the service
}).bind(this.injectedService))
```

Comment: is a reference to **the component the subscription function was defined in** passed to the service together with that function, so that at the moment when a new value appears the service can call the given function to do some tasks on the component object?

Comment: Please see feedback in my answer.

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant, but it is also nice to know! To put it in other words, I would like to know if via a registered callback function in the service, it is possible to get access to the objects that this callback works on (in my example it is `this.user` and `this`, where `this.user` is assigned a new value and `this` is logged in the console). Is it possible to get access to these objects (`this.user` and `this`) using the service object (meaning its array of registered callbacks)?

Comment: Well, I mean you can always `bind` any object you want to a function, also to callback functions, but I don‘t see any reason why you should want to do this. Maybe you can provide some code where you try to express what you want to achieve (even if it is not syntactically correct). E.g. some call you want to make which is not possible currently.

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle illustrating the problem. You can find it here: https://jsfiddle.net/michalte97/wgyjdthu/10/

Comment: added an additional code snippet. Hope this is what you are aimimg for.

Comment: Actually, I what to `.bind(this)` (the Component object) which will have the same effect as using the arrow function. I don't want to change anything here. I don't want to change the binding, but I want to know how it works. The bound object is not passed '"physically" with the function to the Service object, but it is resolved somehow from the execution context, right? The Service object, which calls the callback function created in the Component object, does not know anything about the Component object itself, it has no reference to it, even if the function manipulates the Component object?

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you are trying to achieve here, but this is far away from a best practice. But you are right, `this` is derived from the scope of where the function is defined. Usually the flow is: different components subscribe to updates from observables in order for **them** to determine what to do with this "pushed" value. If you are trying to change components from different parts of your code, it seems to not be easily maintable from terms of Open-Closed-Principle.